# Google Cloud DNS MX record returns value error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a DNS record set to add google workspace MX records from: https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034

but getting value error:

What does that mean ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide an image of the specific error message ?

are you trying to use "@" for your GCP Cloud DNS zone ?

omitting your private info, can you share a screenshot of the information you are trying to put on your Google Cloud DNS zone ? (an screenshot would be ideal)

You mentioned "but getting value error:", but no error message is shown, can you be more specific on this ?

Comment: @Frank updated!

Answer (score 0):

The MX priority number is missing, can you try:

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com
```

Instead of

> aspmx.l.google.com

Comment: I moved to another hosting provider, support package is too expensive